# How to handle multiple transaction in spring

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Hi please can anyone help me out on how to handle multiple transaction in spring. For example i am trying to register an user in my application. I have collected data from my UI layer.now i need to do the following activities

1. save the data into multiple tables in database.
2. need to send an email & sms to the user containing username and password
3. send an notification email to admin
4. update some other table value.

Now if something goes wrong in above 4 steps application should able to revert everything and display the error message.

How can I handle these task in spring??

Comment: Too broad, what have you tried so far?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Please show us some of your work, the community will help you when you are stuck, but no one here will do your complete work..

Comment: *"Now if something goes wrong in above 4 steps application should able to revert everything"* Just run it in a single transaction instead of multiple transactions?

Comment: @BalusC I have yet to see a transactional mail and sms service. Although you could try and send a cancel email ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your Database modification into a Service with @Transactional annotation and change the order about what you just said.

```
        //This two step in the same service with @Transactional annotation.
        1. save the data into multiple tables in database.
        2. update some other table value.
        //Once you save on database and everything it´s ok you can send emails without any problem since you dont have to rollback. 
        3. send an email & sms to the user containing username and password
        4. send an notification email to admin
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is no way to treat email-sending as a transactional resource the same as a database!** Once an email has been sent, it is difficult to call it back. In this field there simply is the infrastructure missing that provides all that handy transactional committal and rollback functionality that you get with databases.

Your best work-around is to send your emails **after** your database updates have been successfully committed. You can make your database updates transactional with Spring's `DataSourceTransaction` Manager and @`Transaction` or one of the other "two-thousand" ways of [doing this with Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

To do the post-transaction committal sending of your email, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331388/transaction-and-sending-an-email). Personally, I favor the idea to use a *transaction after commit hook* to send "email-trigger-messages" to a standalone *Message Queue* like [HornetQ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hornetq/). That way, you can use the queue's out-off-the-box failover mechanism to ensure that your emails will definitely get be delivered.